# php for array implode the data

Tags: php, arrays, implode

```
$Q = $_POST['quantity'];
$_SESSION['quantity'][] = array($Q);
```

there is have the error of this code

```
echo implode("  ",$_SESSION['quantity']);
```

it says that

> Notice: Array to string conversion in

how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below:

```
$_SESSION['quantity'][] = $_POST['quantity']; //assign quantity to session
echo implode("  ",$_SESSION['quantity']); //implode as string and echo
```

Sample example:- https://3v4l.org/h6L9j

Note:-

`$_SESSION['quantity'][]` represent that it's an array.

And when you are doing:

```
$_SESSION['quantity'][] = array($Q);
```

that means you are creating array inside array. And hens `implode()` giving you error.

look this URL to understand your issue (what i explained in notes): https://3v4l.org/32TUI

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below code; please check whether input is an array

```
if(is_array($_POST['quantity'])) {
    for($i=0;$i< count($_POST['quantity']);$i++){ 
        $_SESSION['quantity'][] = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    }
}
```